# Updater function for DataGridView

Tags: c#, json, datagridview, datagrid

I have 3 tables (one is populated with JSON file, second with fixed information, third is a calculation from first and second data), all of them are presented in DGV1, DGV2 and DGV3.
Now I'm trying to create updater() where it will re-download the JSON and re-do the calculation in both first and third table.
Here is my code in `updater()`:

```
    public void updater()
    {
        table.Rows.Clear();
        table.Columns.Clear();
        table3.Rows.Clear();
        table3.Columns.Clear();
        table.Clear();
        table3.Clear();
        DataGridView1.Refresh();
        dataGridView3.Refresh();

        // refill data grid view 1
        loadJSONfromAPIandSave();
        loadingJSONtoDGV1();
        DataGridView1.Refresh();
        // refill data grid view 3
        DGV3Fill();
    }
```

DGV1 pass and get filled perfectly. However, DGV3 gets Null exception as seems that it can't see the data in DGV1 ....
so any suggestions ?

DGV3Fill():

```
    public void DGV3Fill()
    {


        table3.Columns.Add("Algorithm");
        table3.Columns.Add("Profit");
        dataGridView3.DataSource = table3;
        for (int i = 0; i < ZpoolAlgoArray.Length; i++)
        {

            if (ZpoolAlgoArray[i] == "blakecoin" | ZpoolAlgoArray[i] == "blake2s" | ZpoolAlgoArray[i] == "decred" | ZpoolAlgoArray[i] == "keccak" | ZpoolAlgoArray[i] == "quark" | ZpoolAlgoArray[i] == "qubit" | ZpoolAlgoArray[i] == "x17")
            {
                double X = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView1[10, i].Value) * ((Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView2[1, i].Value)) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024));
                double Y = Math.Round(X, 8) * BTCVal();
                table3.Rows.Add(ZpoolAlgoArray[i],  Y ); // NULL EXCEPTION HERE! (i=1, ZpoolAlgoArray[1]="blakecoin", Y=2.8)

            }
            else
            {
                double X = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView1[10, i].Value) * ((Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView2[1, i].Value)) / (1024 * 1024));
                double Y = Math.Round(X, 8)*BTCVal();
                table3.Rows.Add(ZpoolAlgoArray[i], Y );
            }



        }


    }
```

Solved! this was the issue (I had a sorting function that was locking the table)

```
    dataGridView3.Sort(dataGridView3.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

Comment: I suggest you read [ask] and take the [tour], you should also tell us where the error happens.  As is this is too broad and a dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Plutonix appreciating your time, but I know what is a Nullexception and it doesn't solve it. and I didn't want to submit a 200 lines code as nobody will have the time to dig through it (I don't mind that though), so I just submit a simple request since all the loading functions are working well being called the first time (during app start). it's all about updating data in DGV1, DGV3 and their datasource table1 and table3. thanks.

Comment: If you know what an NRE is, then you should also know how to fix it.  It seems *very* unlikely DGV3 is actually null.  it seems more likely something else is null that `DGV3Fill()` uses - we cant know that because you did not include that code...or even tell us what line the exception happens on.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix you know NRE better than me, so I attached DGV3Fill(), appreciating your help. thanks